# Styling MagnificPopup Image

Tags: jquery, html, css, magnific-popup

I have a gallery of thumbnails with with a magnificPopup call. It is all working though I am unable to style the called image. At this point it remains behind all content. Does anyone know what class I can use to resolve this?

I'm not sure if this is an issue but as a note, most of the other content in the application has a `z-index` specified.

```html
<div class="column">
  <a href="staff/anthony.jpg" class="without-caption image-link"><img src="staff/anthony.jpg" class="team" width="172" height="115" /></a>
  <a href="staff/cmay.jpg" class="team without-caption image-link"><img src="staff/cmay.jpg" class="team" width="172" height="115" /></a>
  <a href="staff/ed.jpg" class="team without-caption image-link"><img src="staff/ed.jpg" class="team" width="172" height="115" /></a>
  <a href="staff/gregg.jpg" class="team without-caption image-link"><img src="staff/gregg.jpg" class="team" width="172" height="115" /></a>
  <a href="staff/haven.jpg" class="team without-caption image-link"><img src="staff/haven.jpg" class="team" width="172" height="115" /></a>
  <a href="staff/heidi.jpg" class="team without-caption image-link"><img src="staff/heidi.jpg" class="team" width="172" height="115" /></a>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.without-caption').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    closeBtnInside: false,
    image: {
      verticalFit: true
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: It sounds like you just need to add a `z-index` to whatever CSS class is placed on the HTML content generated by the MagnificPopup

Comment: I agree, but I cannot figure out what class is being added to the content. I went through each element and added a z-index but it none of them affected the image.

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM with dev tools to see where the z-index needs to be overridden? If you create an MCVE of the issue we may be able to help more effectively.

Comment: I have... I went through each class in the markup and tried to override. I am looking closer to see if I am missing something. I probably will not be able to create a MCVE for this anytime soon.